# Switching between php versions in homestead

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

Using one homestead (ubuntu 16.04) instance which is simplest way to switching between PHP versions.

Comment: If you like my answer, i will add as answer so you can accept it :)
here is what i found, i read thru and looks pretty simple:
https://github.com/mnshankar/settler53
http://juliangut.com/blog/php-5-7-homestead

Comment: What do you mean by 'switching'? You want to change version to 7 and leave or be able to switch between versions?

Comment: @ Randall Flagg I want to be able switching between versions.

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know, but I use this command.

sudo update-alternatives --config php